# Using IDictionary in controller method ASP.NET MVC 4/JSON

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm attempting to post data using AJAX back to an ASP.NET MVC Controller with a viewModel like so:

```
public class FunkyThingUpdateModel
{
   public int FunkyThing_ID{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public IDictionary SizesAvailable{ get; set;}
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm struggling to get the model binder to bind to the IDicationary.
If in the JSON passed to the controller the `sizesAvailable` is `null` then the controller method is called successfully.  However if there is data in sizesAvailable then I'm getting an internal server error 500.

My JSON is formatted as follows:

```
 {"FunkyThing_ID":1,"Name":"Pogo Stick","SizesAvailable":{"1":"Extra
 Large","2":"Extra Tiddly"}}
```

What I'm not sure is - am I trying to do something impossible.  Is there a way of binding to an IDictionary - if not what is the best alternative?

Or does my JSON just need to be formatted in a different fashion?

I found a number of similar questions on here, but most of them are quite old.

There seemed to be some indications that this was possible in MVC 4 which I'm using - but I could have been misunderstanding the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, But i think you have to specify Generic interface definition for the object to be created.

```
public IDictionary<int, string> SizesAvailable{ get; set;}
```

and also you have to change the data in ajax definition to notify SizesAvailable as array

```
$.ajax({
    url:'your url', 
    type: 'post', 
    contentType : 'application/json', 
    data: JSON.stringify({FunkyThing_ID:1, Name:"Pogo Stick", SizesAvailable:[{key: 1, value:"Extra Large"},{key:2, value: "Extra Tiddly"}]}), 
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

**Edit**

If your intention is to only get string array(not a dictionary) of sizes, change

```
public string[] SizesAvailable{ get; set;}
```

and send data as,

```
data: JSON.stringify({FunkyThing_ID:1, Name:"Pogo Stick", SizesAvailable:["Extra Large","Extra Tiddly"]}),
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that got it.  I was after the dictionary the keys being ID's.
Much appreciated!